# Real projects using clojure Avout.io, existent drawbacks and/or alternatives

Tags: clojure, apache-zookeeper

I'm just checking the existence of [avout.io](http://avout.io/) "Distributed State in Clojure" to use on top of azookeper project. 
I'm trying to know if this library is suitable for production uses and to know some real projects, alternatives, drawbacks and/or feedback... but I don't find much information about the library (maybe because the name 'avout' is misunderstanding by the search engines as 'about')

Also I noted that the last meaningful commit was authored 2 years ago...

Can anyone purpose any help or path to get into?

Thanks!

Comment: It is used by the British newspaper DailyMail. That what they said in EuroClojure 2013

Comment: On the clojure irc channel one participant tell me that the project caribou will start to use it soon

Answer (score 1):

At the DailyMail it was pulled out due to:

https://github.com/liebke/avout/issues/10
and
https://github.com/liebke/avout/issues/2

and because it doesn't appear to be actively maintained.